# INSERT RETURNING and partitioning POSTGRESQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, triggers, sequence, database-partitioning

Recently I've worked with partition table on portgres. I have some problems about `INSERT RETURNING id` . This is my trigger function and trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_port_vessels_insert_trigger_auto()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
  insert_sql TEXT;
  week_num INTEGER;
  year_num INTEGER;
  partition_table VARCHAR;
  prefix_partition_table VARCHAR :='port_vessels_p_';
BEGIN
  SELECT CAST (EXTRACT(WEEK FROM NEW.created_at) AS INTEGER) INTO week_num;
  SELECT CAST (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NEW.created_at) AS INTEGER) INTO year_num;
  partition_table :=  prefix_partition_table || year_num || '_' || week_num;
  insert_sql := 'INSERT INTO ' || partition_table || ' VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9)';
  EXECUTE insert_sql
  USING NEW.id, NEW.port_id, NEW.vessel_id,
    NEW.last_position_updated_at, NEW.nav_status_code,
    NEW.created_at, NEW.updated_at, NEW.berth_id,
    NEW.berth_shift_id;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER f_port_vessels_insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON port_vessels
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_port_vessels_insert_trigger_auto();
```

I google all of them, and see a solution create a view, created trigger  `insert instead on the view` instead of table. I think it's fine if we working only on the db, but I use Active Record in Rails, I don't want to change my model much more, so anyone experiences this situation? Or have another way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of re-inventing the wheel, you should (on PostgreSQL v10 or later) use [*declarative partitioning*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE).

Comment: How does inheritance partitioning solve `RETURNING` problem?

Comment: Um, I guess it doesn't. I have amended the answer.